# Apple iPhone 6 retaining personal information after Erase All Content and Settings

Tags: iphone, ios, setup, secure-erase

I have an iPhone 6 that I am giving to a family member as I upgraded my phone.

I "Wiped" all my data with `Erase All Content and Settings` however it is still retaining information such as my full name in the `Health` app for example.

It doesn't have a sim card in it.

It was set up using the family members iPad when you bring it close and take a photo of the on screen stars (sorry I don't know the correct term for this process).

Any ideas how I can be confident all my personal data is deleted?

Comment: Did you sign out of iCloud before erasing?

Comment: No, but the second time i selected `Erase All Content and Settings` it was signed into the family members iCloud account.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351)?

Comment: @fsb I did not, do I need to re sign in on my old device?

Comment: If you're still seeing some of your personal data then I would recommend you follow Apple's directions for completely removing your info from that iPhone.  FWIW, I've successfully erased about 6 iPhones over the years by following those directions and I've never had a problem.

Comment: @fsb so i need to sign out of the family members account, then sign back into mine?